# Modeling a kitchen sink - Bevel issue

Tags: modeling, extrude, bevel

**UPDATE:** Included the .blend file: [image]

Blender novice here. I'm trying to model a kitchen sink and i'm having an issue immediately with trying to bevel a certain edge. I've looked through various of the suggested questions/answers but it didn't really help me. This is the sink i'm trying to model:

[image]

I've created the basic mesh in blender as shown below:

Solid view:

[image]

Wireframe view:

[image]

I'm trying to bevel the edge as shown below but the beveling doesn't seem to happen along the expected edges:

[image]

By contrast, when i attempt it on one of the other edge, it seems to happen as expected:

[image]

I suspect it's not working because there are additional edges/vertices that i need to be taking into account or including at the bevel attempt? Could someone assist?

Many thanks!

Comment: first make sure you've applied the scale in Object mode, and that there is no overlapping vertices. If it still doesn't work please share your file

Comment: I applied the scale so that's not the issue. I also don't think there are overlapping vertices but not completely sure about that. I've edited the question and attached the .blend file.

Comment: yes you have ovelapping vertices, so select all and press alt M > Merge by Distance, then bevel again

Comment: aha - thanks moonboots, that fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1):

I have opened your file and checked that you have 26 overlapping vertices. try going to mesh then clean up - merge by distance.